# how to create widget in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, widget, field

This is my custom layout which was same as android `linear layout`

```
public class Custom_TopField extends VerticalFieldManager {
    private static final int FIELD_HEIGHT = 70;

    private String _text;

    Custom_TopField(int color, String text) {
        super(Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL);
        _text = text;

        Background background = BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(color);
        setBackground(background);
    }

    protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
        width = Math.min(width, getPreferredWidth());
        height = Math.min(height, getPreferredHeight());
        setExtent(width, height);
    }

    public int getPreferredHeight() {
        return FIELD_HEIGHT;
    }

    public int getPreferredWidth() {
        return Display.getWidth();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        int rectHeight = getPreferredHeight();
        int rectWidth = getPreferredWidth();

        Font font = Font.getDefault().derive(Font.BOLD, 65);
        graphics.drawRect(0, 0, rectWidth, rectHeight);
        graphics.drawText(_text, rectWidth / 2, 10);
        graphics.setFont(font);
        graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        super.paint(graphics);
    }
}
```

Output = background red and font = black

What I want is background red, font white, font size 40.

I also want to know how to create widget programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the font to white and the size to 40 change the paint as follows:

```
public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
    int rectHeight = getPreferredHeight();
    int rectWidth = getPreferredWidth();

    Font font = Font.getDefault().derive(Font.BOLD, 40);
    graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    graphics.setFont(font);
    graphics.drawRect(0, 0, rectWidth, rectHeight);
    graphics.drawText(_text, rectWidth / 2, 10);
    super.paint(graphics);
}
```

Comment: got it. what about create a textview(android) in blackberry?

Comment: What do you mean with textview?

Comment: the textview widget in android one which is static text, i want to call in blackberry

Comment: check RichTextField ... is that what you want?

Comment: yeah, how about others such as edittext etc... or got tutorial or example?